# Drawing boxes and width for each box is ignored and general spacing not working

Tags: html, css

Running into a lot of problems here:

```
.apple {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: red;
background-color: blue;
text-align: justify;

}
```

for the entire code, please visit: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jennielisajane/4sb8upa6/#&togetherjs=pabeHPuntm

(I would appreciate if you could collaborate directly on jsfiddle)

Hi, I want these boxes to be spaced equally vertically. Right now it isn't spaced.

Also I set the width and height of each box and somehow only the third box respects width and height in css. Why is this happening?

Also how do you center texts horizontally for first and second boxes?

I also want to center the text in the third box vertically.

Thank you in advance.

Provided in the link above

https://jsfiddle.net/jennielisajane/4sb8upa6/#&togetherjs=pabeHPuntm

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the `div` tags with classes apple, bee and orange.

Should be:

```
<div class="gen">
    <div class="apple">
        <div>apple</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bee">
        <div>bee</div>
    </div>
    <div class="orange">
        <div>orange</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="gen">
    <div class="apple"> <div>apple</div>
    <div class="bee"> <div>bee</div>
    <div class="orange"> <div>orange</div>
</div>
```